# usage of "complain of sth"

Tags: word-usage

[From the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/complain-of-sth)

> complain of sth: to tell other people that something is making you feel ill

> She's been complaining of a bad back recently.

I understand the meaning of it.  I’d just like to know who the listener usually is.

In this particular example, would she say that to her friends, her doctor or both?

Comment: She is not saying it to anyone. Someone is saying it about her to a third party.

Comment: @BruceMurray Thank you. In real life, who is the speaker?

Comment: I have no idea.  That can't be determined from the text.

Comment: @BruceMurray Sorry, I should have said "who could be the speaker".  I agree with you that there is no more context. Which is needed to make up to understand the meaning better, right?  So could you please help me to make up a context for it?

Comment: Robert, she would say it to both. She has probably said "Oh! My back hurts" or similar, a number of times in her everyday life, and eventually decided to see a doctor about it.

Comment: The speaker could be anyone who has heard her complain. E.g. in an office — "Where's Mary?" "Mary has a medical appointment today. She said that she's going to see a physiotherapist about her back" "Yeah, she's been complaining of a bad back recently. Hopefully she gets it all sorted out."